# iTunes asking for password for wrong iTunes account

Tags: itunes, apple-id

I purchased a new phone at Sam's club and they transferred the data from my old iPhone to my new iPhone. But now more and more apps will not update with out the password for an iTunes account that I don't know who's is. Even apps that I have downloaded since that data transfer have this problem. I have tried rebooting my iPhone, logging in and out of iTunes, and deleting and reinstalling the app but nothing works.

Comment: What error do they give?

Comment: If they set it up you should go ask why they used a new applied and what the password is.  Also ask why they didn't use your existing appleid

Comment: The problem is that I live 2 hrs from the location I purchased the phone

Comment: You will have to go back, since they screwed up. You could call them to get the log in information, but I doubt they will give it to you.

Answer (score 1):

Try signing out of iTunes on your iPhone and signing in as your Apple ID. After you login as the right account, delete all the apps you have downloaded and redownload them.

Comment: The OP may lose information not backed up when deleting the apps though.